# Unable to read URL

Tags: python

My code is the following, it used to run perfectly for quite a while but suddenly got the error message. Tried other stocks data providers like Google & alpha vantage and got the same error message.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
!pip install ffn
import ffn
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
from pylab import *
import pandas as pd
import pandas_profiling
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from matplotlib import style
%matplotlib inline

stocks = 'alf,mrin,auud,sncr,ddd,ssnt,seac,ttd'     

df = ffn.get(stocks, start='06/18/2021').to_returns().dropna()

print(df.as_format('.2%'))
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(0)
sums = df.select_dtypes(np.number).sum() 
sort_sums = sums.sort_values(ascending = False)
pd.set_option('Display.max_rows', len(stocks))

sharpe = ffn.core.calc_sharpe(df)
sharpe = sharpe.sort_values(ascending = False)
df.append({stocks: sharpe},ignore_index=True)

print(str(sort_sums.as_format('.2%')))
print(sharpe.head(10))
df.shape
```

I'm using Google Colaboratory
Please run the code and you will see the Error message I'm getting (I can't copy it to here).

Please help & thank you very much in advance!

Comment: On which operating system? If on Linux, consider using [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand all the many [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) done by your Python script

Comment: Also, notice that Python is documented to have many [HOWTOs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/index.html). It is [open source software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software), and you are allowed to download its source code (half of which is in C, the other half is in Python), study that source code, and improve it.